# PowerShell RichTextBox ScrollToCaret

Tags: winforms, powershell, richtextbox

So I'm fairly new to building forms in PowerShell; I've tried Saipen PowerShell Studio and just can't get on with it so I'm sticking to ICE and doing all the heavy lifting myself - which can be a pain when I come up against something I've never seen before.

In this case I have a RichTextBox that I'd like to autoscroll. I've seen ScrollToCaret all over the internet for C#, and the Saipen forums suggest using it, but in both cases the full PS code is never supplied so I have no idea where to put it. Wherever I've tried, I'm not getting anywhere.

Any help would be really appreciated. I'll also take general advice on whethere or not I'm doing things efficiently. Yeah I know the GUI is butt ugly, only because it's missing all the stuff that's irrelevant to this problem.

```
# Adds .NET assemby's and turns on visual themes in standard PowerShell.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


Function OpenFileDialog { 
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Windows.Forms" ) | Out-Null
  $OBJFORM           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OBJFORM.Filter    = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt"
  $TXTIMPORT         = $OBJFORM.ShowDialog()

  IF ( $TXTIMPORT -eq "OK" )
     { Return $OBJFORM.FileName } }

 Function WriteFile {
   $LINES  = gc $TAB1IMPORT
   $TAB1TEXT.AppendText( "`nGet-Content $TAB1IMPORT" )

   foreach ( $LINE in $LINES )
           { $TAB1TEXT.AppendText( "`n$LINE" )
             Sleep 1 } }



# Creates the parent form and controls
$SDC                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$SDC.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 270,175 )
$SDC.Size             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 900,600 )
$SDC.StartPosition    = "CenterScreen"
$SDC.BackColor        = "Lavender"
$SDC.Font             = "Calibri, 8.5"
$SDC.FormBorderStyle  = "Fixed3D"

$TABC                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$TABC.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 140,20 )
$TABC.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 720,520 )
$TABC.SizeMode        = "Fixed"
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TABC )

# Tab controls
$TAB1                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$TAB1.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 20,20 )
$TAB1.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 100,100 )
$TAB1.Text            = "Migrate Users"
$TABC.Controls.Add( $TAB1 )

#Tab open file button
$TAB1BUTTON           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$TAB1BUTTON.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 50,270 )
$TAB1BUTTON.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 80,20 ) 
$TAB1BUTTON.Text      = "File Import"
$TAB1.Controls.Add( $TAB1BUTTON )

$TAB1BUTTON.Add_Click( { $TAB1IMPORT    = OpenFileDialog
                         $TAB1TEXT.Text = $TAB1TEXT.Text.Clear
                         $TAB1TEXT.AppendText( "PS H:\>$TAB1IMPORT" )
                         WriteFile } )

#Tab 1 Text Box
$TAB1TEXT             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$TAB1TEXT.Location    = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 50,300 )
$TAB1TEXT.Size        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 615,180 )
$TAB1TEXT.Font        = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Consolas",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold ) 
$TAB1TEXT.BackColor   = "Black"
$TAB1TEXT.ForeColor   = "White"
$TAB1TEXT.Multiline   = $TRUE
$TAB1TEXT.Text        = "PS H:\>"
$TAB1TEXT.BorderStyle = "FixedSingle"
$TAB1.Controls.add( $TAB1TEXT )


$SDC.Add_Shown( { $SDC.Activate() } )
$SDC.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ScrollToCaret` method in your `WriteFile` function

```
 Function WriteFile {
   $LINES  = gc $TAB1IMPORT
   $TAB1TEXT.AppendText( "`nGet-Content $TAB1IMPORT" )

   foreach ( $LINE in $LINES )
           { $TAB1TEXT.AppendText( "`n$LINE" )
             $TAB1TEXT.ScrollToCaret()             # here
             Sleep 1 } }
```

---

**edit** - I've come across this many times where a `c#` solution is provided but no PowerShell syntax. You were so close with this one... I got to the solution by using tab-complete.

A better way would be to user `Get-Member` to see what methods are available on an object. This lists `ScrollToCaret` and gives you the method definition:

- `void ...` - does not return anything
- `...()`    - empty brackets so takes no argument

`$TAB1TEXT | Get-Member`

[image: List of $ATABTEXT members]

---

**c# in Powershell in general** - [helpful link](http://executeautomation.com/blog/calling-c-code-in-powershell-and-vice-versa/)

Calling a static method

```
[Class]::StaticMethod(args)
```

Calling an instance method

```
$object.InstanceMethod(args)
```

Getting a property

```
$object.Property
```